# Detect different words in strings of two arrays and output them in third array

Tags: javascript, arrays, string-comparison

I have a function that outputs the different words of two strings. This works fine until I want to iterate over two arrays that contain strings and output a third array that shows me the "extra" words, if there are any.

Code is the following:

> let lag  =  {{query29.data.lag }}
>
> let real =  {{query29.data.produkte}}
>
> ```
> function getDifference(a, b)
> {
>     var i = 0;
>     var j = 0;
>     var result = "";
>
>     while (j < b.length)
>     {
>      if (a[i] != b[j] || i == a.length)
>          result += b[j];
>      else
>          i++;
>      j++;
>     }
>     return result;
> }
> ```
>
> var test = [getDifference(lag, real)]
>
> return {lag, real, test}

Now my output is an object of the three arrays lag, real and test but while lag and real both have 307 items, test has one long item listing all the output delivered by the function.

How do I achieve that the function will be called 307 times for every single item of lag, comparing it to real, showing me an array of 307 items with the different words?

Comment: It would help if you could add a simple example of input, actual output and expected output.

Comment: so **example input** would be: lag = ['hi,tim', 'hey', 'what,why']; real = ['hi', 'hey', 'what'] the **actual output** test = ['tim, why'] and the **expected output**: test = ['tim', null, 'why']

Comment: So the goal is to split the `lag` strings on comma, and remove matching strings that are in the `real` array at the same index? What if `lag = ['hi,tim,banana', 'hey', 'what,why, when']`? Or do the string elements in `lag` have at most two comma-separated words?

Comment: That is correct. And the function also works if there are more than two comma-separated words in the string

Answer (score 0):

You can use some functional evaluations as follow:

```js
function getDifference(a, b) {
   return a.filter(x => !b.some(y => y == x));
}
```